# Best place for Pricing Section?

Tags: usability, website-design, ux-designer

I am currently designing a web services websites and i need some feedback regarding to pricing section,

I am unsure if it's OK to include pricing table on the landing page or it should be on a separate page for pricing.

The Landing page i made are consist of:

- Header Section
- Overview Section (slider)
- Our Services (web design & Development/logo/seo)
- About Us
- Pricing Section(unsure)
- Contact Form Section
- Footer Section

Comment: Please provide more information. Every situation differs on the context, so if you provide more information we would be able to help you.

Comment: i made some edits  on my question, feel free to give me feedback thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you expect users to search for pricing instantly it's a good idea to show them Landing page. It could also be that the pricing IS one of your USP's (i.e. cheapest on the market).

In that case it's smart to be proud of your pricing and show it off on the landing page. In that case you would be introducing another step towards finding the information by hiding it behind a different page.

This becomes a different story if you first need to convince people about your services and charm them with your USP's. In that case the focus would be the story you tell about your services, in which you link to the pricing (which would then be placed in a seperate page).

Pricing on a seperate page does have advantages: you can provide additional information, detail about packages and contact options such as livechat.